# Open a second JavaFX window from outside start

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx, javafx-8, stage

How can I open a secondary JavaFX window (stage) from outside the "start" method? For example,

```
public class GUI_Test extends Application {
static Stage secondStage;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
    showSecondWin();
}

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(
            new VBox(
                    new Label("window 1"))));
    primaryStage.show();

    secondStage = new Stage();
}

public static void showSecondWin() {
    secondStage.setScene(new Scene(
            new VBox(
                    new Label("window 2"))));
    secondStage.show();
}
}
```

The above code shows only the first window ("primaryStage"), and (only) when I close it an `java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException` error message appears.

**James_D said there is a way to open a second window from outside start. How can this be achieved?**

Comment: It's different from other questions because I don't want to open the second window using a button, or anything else from the start() method, as I explained in my comment to sillyfly.

Comment: You should think of the `start()` method in a JavaFX application as a replacement for the `main()` method in a "traditional" (i.e. not JavaFX) application. (In JavaFX, you don't even need a `main()` method!) So `start()` is the entry point for the application: everything is initiated from that point. It doesn't really make sense to ask to do something that's not eventually triggered by the `start()` method. Maybe [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37579645) will help.

Comment: @James_D I want to create the second window from a method (not start), within the application class. The SecondWin method is called by another class.

Comment: @James_D I'm creating a strategy game, a very basic game of Civilization (a video game series, you may know it). I want that when a player clicks on a action button when it's not his turn, a new window will appear with a message ("It's not your turn" or something like that). I cant display that window from the start() method.

Comment: @James_D I'm trying to avoid putting the logic in the start method. I need to open a second window in a few other situations, in which putting the entire logic in the start method would be extremely clumsy. Are you sure there isn't a way to avoid putting the logic in start?

Comment: At this point, your question is completely unclear. Your edits indicate the problem is completely different to the code you posted. Your comments directly contradict each other: " I don't want to open the second window using a button" and "I want that when a player clicks on a action button when it's not his turn, a new window will appear", for example. You need to explain what the actual problem is, perhaps even in a new question, as I think the original question you posted here is correctly answered.

Comment: @James_D I apologize for the confusion. Let me ask a simple question - can you open a second window from outside start? Yes or no.

Comment: Yes, of course you can.

Comment: @James_D So I'm sorry for not being clear enough, but that's basically my question - how can it be done. I rephrased the original question to clarify this. I'll be glad if you'll answer this question, it seems like you know this stuff.

Comment: You haven't clarified anything. You have posted code in the question that does exactly what you say you want (opens a window from outside start). You are getting the exception because you cannot invoke the method from where you are trying to invoke it, as is already clearly and concisely explained in the answer. But there is nothing wrong with the definition of showSecondWin. Ending this discussion as it seems fruitless.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the documentation for [`Application`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/application/Application.html#launch-java.lang.String...-):

> The launch method does not return until the application has exited, either via a call to Platform.exit or all of the application windows have been closed.

This means the second line in your `main` method only gets called after the JavaFX thread exits, so you cannot create any more stages.

You could create and show your second stage inside the `start` method. If that's not a valid option please try to explain what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I want to open a dialog window that is triggered from outside the start method. Maybe I can do something with the stage.hide() method? I tried to play with it a bit, but it didn't work...

Comment: What is the trigger to opening the other stage? Why can't it be expressed until the application exits?

Comment: I want to create the second window from a method (not start), within the application class. The SecondWin method is called by another class.

Comment: Sounds to me like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).  Could you please explain what exactly you are trying to achieve, regardless of how you think you may want to implement it?

Comment: Opening a second window (dialog) from outside start() (in several occasions), as the title says.