# Java Tasks setOnSucceded does not work

Tags: java, task, executorservice

Ihave a problem, similiar to this, and it does not work. Well the Task is running fine, but the 'setOnSucceeded' or the 'setOnFailed' never runns. I use an 'ExecutorService'. Also the Programm is never done, it just keeps running. I tried it with 'new Thread(task).start();' and then it is sasy build successfully, but the 'setOnSucceeded' doesn't fire either.

```
package stackoverflow;

import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import javafx.concurrent.Task;
import javafx.concurrent.WorkerStateEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;

public class X {

    private ExecutorService exec;

    public X() {
        exec = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
        run();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        X x = new X();
    }

    private void run() {
        Task<Void> task = new Task<Void>() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                System.out.println("In Task");
                this.succeeded();
            }

            @Override
            protected Void call() throws Exception {
                throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
            }
        };

        task.setOnSucceeded((WorkerStateEvent event) -> {
            System.out.println("In set on Succeded");
        });

        task.setOnFailed((WorkerStateEvent event) -> {
            System.out.println("In Failed");
        });

        exec.execute(task);
    }

}
```

Comment: This code does not compile

Comment: @user6690200 ups, I changed it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I start one thread for my code and one for a JavaFX Application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37579645/how-do-i-start-one-thread-for-my-code-and-one-for-a-javafx-application)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The point of JavaFX utility classes is that JavaFX takes care of the threading et all. So you don't need to create any `ExecutorService` or `Thread` or whatever. On the other hand, you need to launch an `Application`, and then create a `Service` which creates a `Task`.

Also, you don't need to override `run()`, because JavaFX already implemented it. The method where the logic goes is `call()`. So, after all this mambo-jambo, JavaFX will create the `succeeded()` method for you. Don't call it manually because that only causes confusion. On the other hand, you can override it, so you can have yet another option for `succeeded()` hook.

So, here is the code:

```
package stackoverflow;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.concurrent.Service;
import javafx.concurrent.Task;
import javafx.concurrent.WorkerStateEvent;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

// extending Application
public class X extends Application {

    // Empty constructor. I just put it here so we know explicitly that a no-arg construcor exists.
    public X() {
        // NOP
    }

    @Override
    // a hook for starting the Applicatoin
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        run();
    }

    // This is a proper entry point of a JavaFX application
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    private void run() {
        // creating a service, then running it
        ExampleService service = new ExampleService();
        service.start();
    }

    // this is the dummy service
    private static class ExampleService extends Service<Void> {

        @Override
        protected Task<Void> createTask() {
            Task<Void> task = new Task<Void>() {

                @Override
                protected Void call() throws Exception {
                    System.out.println("called");
                    // for Task<Void> we should return null
                    return null;
                }

                @Override
                protected void succeeded() {
                    // one hook - overriding
                    super.succeeded();
                    System.out.println("Succeded");
                }

                @Override
                protected void failed() {
                    // one hook - overriding
                    super.failed();
                    System.out.println("Failed");
                }
            };

            task.setOnSucceeded((WorkerStateEvent event) -> {
                // another hook - callback lambda
                System.out.println("In set on Succeded");
            });

            task.setOnFailed((WorkerStateEvent event) -> {
                // another hook - callback lambda
                System.out.println("In Failed");
            });
            return task;
        }

    }

}
```

#### Update

I changed the `start()` and the `call()` methods to see what's going on:

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    System.out.println("--> in start: " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
    Thread.dumpStack();
    run();
}


            @Override
            protected Void call() throws Exception {
                System.out.println("called in thread: " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
                Thread.dumpStack();
                return null;
            }
```

The `start()` is invoked from the `JavaFX Application Thread` through some sort of `InvokeLaterDispatcher`.

The `call()`  method is invoked from `Thread-4` from a `java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor`. JavaFX seems to be exceptionally well designed in regards of asynchronous tasks. In Swing we had to maintain our thread pools. In JavaFX we don't need to, unless we have a special need that JavaFX can't handle. I find this possible, but unlikely.

Comment: I used the executor Service because I dynamically create tasks later on

Comment: I modified the code a little to show more debug data. Apparently, JavaFX already uses a `ThreadPoolExecutor`. Adding the detail to the answer.